# Calculate pick rate

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I work for a warehouse where employees are required to pick items for delivery. We have a split shift. It starts at 9.00am to 12.45pm and then from 7.00pm to 10.45. So that is total of 7.5 hours of picking time and 6.25hrs of break in between. NOw an average employee picks at the rate of about 100 items per hour, so his pick rate in the first shift should average to about 100. This is calculated by our system, however when they come back after the 6.25 hour break, the system calculates their pick rate on the average of total hours since they started which by then is 10 hours so their Pick rate has now dropped considerably to about 30. So if if they pick at 100 per hour from then their pick rate on the system will show low, which of course is not the true representation.

Can someone help me calculate manually (in excel) how much the actual pick rate will be if the picker has picked for the full 7.5 hours. If for example he picked on an average pick rate of 95 in the second half.

Thanks in advance. Please let me know if there any further questions.

Comment: SO can't help unless you show an example of your input, desired output and what you have tried. If you want a code writing service, you should look elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The pick rate formula is items picked / hours of work. Your mistake is to say hours of work = leave time - start time, since there is 6.25 hours of non-work time during the break. If your employees work both shifts, why not simply subtract 6.25 before you divide? Like this: PickRate = ItemsPicked / (LeaveTime - StartTime - 6.25)

Answer (score 0):

As both halves of the shift are the same length you can simply average the pick rate for both halves, e.g.

`=AVERAGE(90,100)`

or if you have those rates in A2 and B2

`=AVERAGE(A2,B2)`

That would give you 95 in your example, of course

If the shift halves were **different lengths** that wouldn't be so easy, you'd need to multiply the pick rate by the hours for each half, add those together then divide by the total hours to get the overall pick rate

Answer (score 0):

I am interpreting your question as being how do you correct incorrect stats that come out of your system.

You say the system calculated based on 10 hours ("since they started") - i.e. 1245-1045.  Confusing, because they actually started at 9am right?

But **If your system gives you the pick rate based on items/10 hrs** (which, as you say is wrong). Then you can adjust this bad calc for the second shift by *2.67.

e.g. "real" pick rate is 95, and "real" pick time (7-10:45) is 3.75 hours.  95*3.75 =356 items picked and your system will therefore show pick rate of 356/10 = 35.6.

35.5*2.67 gives you the 'real' average pick rate of 95. This is average for the second shift.

2.67 is simply 10/3.75 - so it is the same multiple nomatter the pick rate.

IF however, the system calculates pick rate based on the WHOLE day (9am-1045pm) then the adjustment to get daily average is different - it is 1.83.  Given you mentioned 30, I figured this isn't the case but including for clarity.